# PhalconPHP: eager load related records?

Tags: php, orm, phalcon

I'm wondering what the best way to do this with Phalcon is...

I have these two models:  Companies  and  CompanyTitles.

Companies have a one to many relationship with CompanyTitles.

When I do a call to get all the companies, like so:

```
$companies = Companies::find($params)
```

I can get all of the companyTitles of a particular company via

```
$companies[0]->companyTitles
```

for example.  However, is there a way to get the companyTitles for all of them all at once so that we only make a single call to the database?!

What I'm doing is building an API, and I want to be able to send back something like this:

```
{
    "companies": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Bob Co"
            "companyTitles": [1, 2, 3, 4]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            ...
        }
 }
```

(I just put ids there as placeholders, but you get the idea.  Though, technically, it could be ids or objects.)

Comment: [This](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/1117) seems to be relevant. Might want to watch it. Also proves the point below ;)

Comment: oh well, it seems nice code != performant code in this case. The guys over Phalcon prefer to have a simplistic ORM that complicates your system, instead of having readable code that might not be that performant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>Yes and</del> No. <del>Yes: you can use a subquery to select all company title ids into a separate field and manually digest it into array.</del> Actually no… according to [this](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/496).

No: you can't do that if you want to keep your one to many relations and be able to do `$companies[0]->companyTitles` without loading all of that data. That would be barely possible and very hacky in plain sql.

Any ORM is an attempt to abstract away from dealing directly with sql, which will always cost you functionality (can't account for everything without reinventing the wheel) and performance (query compilation, non-optimal queries, multiple queries, etc) vs using plain sql. Phalcon is an amazing project, but like other frameworks with ORM support or ORM frameworks, it's not going to outsmart you in situations like this. I've stopped using the native Phalcon models after hitting too many dead ends, they are awesome for simple tasks, but for something more complex they run into problems.

If your priority is the time, then stick with what you have. Extra 10-50 ms for an extra query won't change much. If you need a maintainable codebase, this is a big and long running project, then this is a risky way forward. When things get more complicated this gets truly unreliable. Use an more mature ORM, I'm personally having a great success with [illuminate/database](https://github.com/illuminate/database) for building queries and manually mapping data to models – I have to say though this was pretty time consuming.

Comment: I would just like to add here that you are underpowering many other ORMs around the PHPland. Many other frameworks, such as Yii or Laravel certainly support "advanced" features like eager-loading relationships. It's Phalcon's to blame if it doesn't support such a simple feature to improve our project's performance without having to write 5+ lines of SQL/PHQL. This is not to "outsmart you", this is _basic_. And stuffing another ORM in the project is a bit odd, as it will never be as performant as pure Phalcon could be.